# ASP.NET MVC 2 Validating A Strongly Typed Model List With Data Annotations Exception When Using EnableClientValidation()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, client-side

Here is the buddy class used to add data annotation validators to a Entity Framework model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Result_Validation))]
public partial class Result
{

}

[Bind(Include = "Title,Description")]
public class Result_Validation
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IList<Result>>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
  <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
  <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
  <fieldset>
    <% for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { %>
      <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].Title)%>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Title)%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Title)%>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].Description)%>
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].Description)%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Description)%>
      </div>
    <% } %>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine for server side validaton, but as soon as I drop the Html.EnableClientValidation(); in there I get this error: "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

..and it points to this line in the view:

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Title)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting

```
<% Html.ValidationSummary(); %>
```

before

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```